# Can you combine the white days and shawwal?

Tags: sawm

I was fasting shawwal and then realized that it was also the white days. Does my fast count?

Comment: What makes you think it's not counted?

Comment: Because it's 2 different fasts. Just like how you can't combine the fasts you missed in Ramadan and shawwal